# python regex: group of groups?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like this

```
s = 'MR1|L2-S1x'
```

The pattern is always the same: one or two characters, optionally followed by a number and a divider in `[|.+:x-]`. This pattern can be repeated until 6 times.

So the matching pattern is clear.

```
p = r'([A-Z]+)(\d)?([|.+:x-]+)'
```

But how to make it match it the string as a group of groups?

More precisely: now I get

```
t=re.search(p,s)
t.groups()
('MR', '1', '|')
```

What I want, though, is

```
('MR', '1', '|'),('L', '2', '-'),('S', '1', 'x')
```

Comment: Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)? `re.search` returns only the first matched group.

Comment: Hehe, time to go to bed for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user "undefined is not a function" (in comments) is correct.
Use [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to get all matching groups.

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = 'MR1|L2-S1x'
>>> p = r'([A-Z]+)(\d)?([|.+:x-]+)'
>>> import re
>>> t = re.findall(p, s)
>>> t
[('MR', '1', '|'), ('L', '2', '-'), ('S', '1', 'x')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
tokens=[]
subject = "MR1|L2-S1xZZ+"
reobj = re.compile(r"([A-Z]{1,2})(\d?)([|.+:x-]?)")
for match in reobj.finditer(subject):
    tokens.append((match.group(1),match.group(2),match.group(3)))
print(tokens)
```

**Output:**

```
[('MR', '1', '|'), ('L', '2', '-'), ('S', '1', 'x'), ('ZZ', '', '+')]
```